# How can I convert negative integer to binary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I need to convert negative number to binary in python.
How can I do it ?

EDIT: I need to use twos complement

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are looking for? Eg. should 255 be `-11111111` or be the 2s complement negative of a 1 byte integer?

Answer (score 0):

```
bin(-2)
#'-0b10'
```

Use the built in `bin`function to get a binary representation.

Comment: I need to use two's complement @Dan Hall